# is it possible to pipe a data frame variable

Tags: r, magrittr

I have two separate operations:

```
allusers$ref <- str_to_upper(allusers$ref)

allusers$ref <- str_trim(allusers$ref)
```

Is it possible to pipe them?

```
allusers$ref <- str_to_upper(allusers$ref) %>% str_trim(allusers$ref)
```

gives

> "Error in match.arg(side) : 'arg' must be of length 1"

and ideally I wouldn't be typing `allusers$..` each time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you may write

```
allusers$ref <- allusers$ref %>% str_to_upper %>% str_trim
```

That's because you want to apply `str_to_upper` and `str_trim` to a string, and by piping `allusers$ref` you indeed pass as the first argument this string.

A somewhat traditional way would be

```
allusers <- allusers %>% mutate(ref = str_trim(str_to_upper(ref)))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you just wanted to do this in base R, the easiest would probably be to use normal function composition…

```
allusers$ref <- str_trim(str_to_upper(allusers$ref))
```

alternatively, you could use `within`:

```
allusers <- within(allusers, {
  ref <- str_to_upper(ref)
  ref <- str_trim(ref)
})
```

or even combine these options:

```
allusers <- within(allusers, {
  ref <- str_trim(str_to_upper(ref))
})
```

though I do tend to use `dplyr` style `mutate` pipes more at the moment it can be good to see some alternatives

Comment: This is not "old school" vs any "new school". This is the base R way of doing things, which (apart from the stringr package) does not need any additional packages to be installed.

Comment: @Spacedman agreed — will change to base R! that said, base R is older while the `magrittr` /  `dplyr` way is the new / currently fashionable way…

Comment: its also the slower, heavier, and more likely to change and break your old code way.